# Как сделать применение JQuery скрипта к нескольким элементам без перезагрузки?

Tags: jquery

Использую библиотеку JQuery Scroll To https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo/blob/master/jquery.scrollTo.js
**Имеется:** список ul с 18 дочерними пунктами li, и блок div с информацией

**Необходимо:** при нажатии на любой из li, чтобы выполнялся скролл вниз к блоку с информацией.

**В чем проблема:** скрипт работает, прокрутка выполняется, но возникает следующее - скрипт как будто привязывается в первому нажатому li и при возврате вверх и нажатии на другой li, ничего не происходит, остается только перезагружать страницу.
Пожалуйста, помогите, скину на чашечку кофе.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.item').click(function() {
    //jQuery.scrollTo('.content');

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="item">1</li>
  <li class="item">2</li>
  <li class="item">3</li>
  <li class="item">4</li>
</ul>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Comment: Код обезличенный сбросьте - ибо тренироваться на предположениях и словесном описании не продуктивно.

Comment: @Coder подскажите, что такое "обезличенный" код?

Comment: Это код, в котором отсутствуют чувствительные или нежелательные ссылки/информация на реальные объеты/объект - то есть, это код, который является оптимизированным по отработке самого механизма, а не содержимого (отсутствие реальных ссылок, названия/домена сайта, паролей и прочей подобной инфо)

Comment: @Coder схематически обновил в шапке

Comment: То есть, вставить вашу схему и подключить скрипт - и все, можно проверять? - Если нет, то, думается, Вы не цените чужое время.

Comment: Ну так, чисто в целях теста, попробуйте паре первым items назначить id и к ним привязать scrollTo. Будет ли работать корректно?

Comment: @VasilyKoshelev хорошо, сейчас попробую. Прикрепил в шапку JS код, которым управляется эта система, забыл изначально

Comment: Можете ещё попробовать вот так сделать
$('.item').each(function(i,elem) {
 $(this).scrollTo('.content');
});
  И странно, у вас что, все указатели ведут на элемент(-ы) с классом content?

Comment: @VasilyKoshelev да, так необходимо, чтобы каждый из item приводил к content

Comment: @VasilyKoshelev вот наглядный пример http://askingyou123.ru.s29.hhos.ru/smartfony.html

Comment: @VasilyKoshelev необходимо, чтобы поломка на клике приводила к выбору устройства

Comment: В консоли ошибки: jQuery is not defined,  $ is not a function. Сам jquery не подключен

Comment: Как разберетесь, возможно, стоит сделать ещё вот так $(document).on('.item', 'click', function () {.... без document ready

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот Вам чистое решение вашего вопроса на JQuery, естественно не используйте более одного h1 на странице, это неправильно )

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.item').click(function() {
    let id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#" + id).offset().top
    }, 1000);

  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
}

.menu {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 300ms all;
}

li:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: #3d3d3d;
}

section {
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

section h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="item" data-id="1">1</li>
    <li class="item" data-id="2">2</li>
    <li class="item" data-id="3">3</li>
    <li class="item" data-id="4">4</li>
    <li class="item" data-id="5">5</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<section id='1'>
  <h1>section 1</h1>
</section>
<section id='2'>
  <h1>section 2</h1>
</section>
<section id='3'>
  <h1>section 3</h1>
</section>
<section id='4'>
  <h1>section 4</h1>
</section>
<section id='5'>
  <h1>section 5</h1>
</section>
```

Comment: Спасибо!
Жду номер Вашей карты в ЛС!

Comment: Доброго вам дня, стековерфлоу это бесплатная помощь :) Так что спасибо, не нужно. И личек в нем тоже нет :) Есть работа предлагайте, а так хватит спасибо ;)